# debugging a django app (locally) in VS Code can't find my database container db

Tags: django, docker, visual-studio-code, docker-compose, virtualenv

When I run a debug configuration in VS Code:

```
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "Django Tests",
        "type": "python",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "${workspaceFolder}/src/manage.py",
        "args": [
            "test",
            "src"
        ],
        "django": true
    }
```

I get this error:
`django.db.utils.OperationalError: could not translate host name "db" to address: Name or service not known`

I don't have this problem when I run the app normally:
`./src/manage.py runserver`

`db` is my containerized postgresql database.

```
services:
  db:
    container_name: db
    build: ./postgresql
    expose:
      - "5432"
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    ...
```

Perhaps I'm not using the proper python path?  I should be running this from within my python virtual environment but I'm not sure how to set that in the VS Code configuration, if that's the problem.

Here's my *settings.py*

```
POSTGRES_HOST = os.environ.get('POSTGRES_HOST', '127.0.0.1')
POSTGRES_PORT = os.environ.get('POSTGRES_PORT', '5432')
```

It seems like db is visible locally:

```
$ docker logs db

PostgreSQL Database directory appears to contain a database; Skipping initialization
```

Here's the command CS Code runs when I try to choose the debug configuration:

```
(venv) me@host:/path/to/myproject/$  env DEBUGPY_LAUNCHER_PORT=36867 /path/to/myproject/venv/bin/python3 /home/me/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2020.3.71659/pythonFiles/lib/python/debugpy/no_wheels/debugpy/launcher /path/to/myproject/src/manage.py runserver --noreload
```

Comment: can you resolve the hostname `db` localy ?

Comment: ```$ docker logs db
PostgreSQL Database directory appears to contain a database; Skipping initialization```

Comment: I meant: does the hostename `db` resolve to an ip-address on your local machine ? (e.g. `ping db`)

Comment: `ping: db: Name or service not known`

Comment: I'm not sure why it's looking for db anyway, when I run locally?  it has no problem when I `manage.py runserver` | EDIT: VS Code seems to be reading my .env file when i run its configuration, so it's setting `POSTGRES_HOSST` to db instead of using the default 127.0.0.1

Comment: then you have `'POSTGRES_HOST', '127.0.0.1'` set. I'm guessing vc-code doesn't know where to find the host: `db`. Could you add `127.0.0.1 db` to your `/etc/hosts` and test again ?

Comment: Thanks for helping me troubleshoot, I added `"envFile": "",` to the VS Code configuration and it's no longer looking for db.  Do you want to put together an answer from this so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to make sure vs-code can find the host `db` or uses `127.0.0.1` directly.

In youre case overriding the environment `"envFile": ""` did the trick.